# custom type conversion from string to some object

Tags: groovy

I want to add conversion to class `String` for object with type `Example`.

When I do like this

```
class Example {
    def x = 5
}

class ExampleConversionCategory {
    static def support = String.&asType
    static Object asType(String self, Class cls) {
        if (cls == Example.class) {
            "convert"
        } else { support(cls) } // argument type mismatch
    }
}

String.mixin(ExampleConversionCategory)

def x = "5" as int
println x
```

I get exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

What is the problem? `cls` has `Class` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were pretty close...

Notice that the `asType` method is implemented by the Groovy's String  extension class, called `StringGroovyMethods`.

So the code that works is this one:

```
import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods

@Canonical
class Example {
    def x = 5
}

class ExampleConversionCategory {
    static final def convert = StringGroovyMethods.&asType

    static def asType( String self, Class cls ) {
        if ( cls == Example ) new Example( x: 10 )
        else convert( self, cls )
    }
}

String.mixin( ExampleConversionCategory )

println "5" as int
println 'A' as Example
```

Which prints:

```
5
Example(10)
```